# SELECT on declared table variable

Tags: postgresql

I have the following pl/pgsql query, but I'm getting `relation "organization_peers" does not exist`, but it does definitely exist, I am declaring it as you can see:

```
DECLARE
    prev_port INT;
    org_id INT;
    port INT;
    organization_peers networking.peers;
BEGIN
    SELECT o.id INTO org_id
    FROM networking.peers p
    LEFT JOIN networking.peer_service_endlets pse ON p.id = pse.peer_id
    LEFT JOIN networking.service_endlets se ON se.id = pse.service_endlet_id
    LEFT JOIN networking.services s ON s.id = se.service_id
    LEFT JOIN billing.organizations o ON o.id = s.organization_id
    WHERE p.id = NEW.id;

    SELECT * INTO organization_peers -- Variable is set here
    FROM networking.peers p
    LEFT JOIN networking.peer_service_endlets pse ON p.id = pse.peer_id
    LEFT JOIN networking.service_endlets se ON se.id = pse.service_endlet_id
    LEFT JOIN networking.services s ON s.id = se.service_id
    LEFT JOIN billing.organizations o ON o.id = s.organization_id
    WHERE o.id = org_id AND p.vwan_port IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY p.vwan_port ASC;

    SELECT p.vwan_port INTO prev_port
    FROM organization_peers -- Fails here
    LIMIT 1;

    --...
```

What's going on here? Why can't it find the declared `organization_peers` table variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rThere are no "table variables" in PostgreSQL. What's going on is this: Whenever you create a table, PostgreSQL automatically declares a composite type with the same name. So `organization_peers` is not a table, but a value of that composite type.

Note that `SELECT ... INTO` doesn't do what you expect it to do. It will only fetch the *first row* of the result set and store it in the variable.  One way to do what you want is to use a temporary table.

To get an attribute from this composite value, you do something like

```
prev_port := organization_peers.vwan_port;
```

Comment: Well I want to perform multiple queries against the entire result though. I've redacted the rest of this script for clarity but I perform multiple queries against `organization_peers` throughout this function. I just thought this would save me from having to rewrite the same query with different where clauses on each, and to save performance. I figured it would be better to grab the set of records I need all at once, then query against that result in subsequent queries.

Comment: Figured it out I just used a temporary table.